# Conditional join in ACCESS SQL based on the value of the field?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two tables I need to join and I'm having a hard time doing it. Here is a simplified example:

Table 1 (T1) with the fields:
Cust_ID, 
Prod_ID,
Type_ID

Table 2 (T2) with the fields:
Cust_ID,
Prod_ID,
Type_ID,
Results

The catch is:
I need all the values from table one. If T1.Cust_ID is Null, then I need all the rows from T2 with the same Prod_ID and Type_ID. If T1.Cust_ID is not Null, then I need only the rows from T2 where T1.Cust_ID=T2.Cust_ID with the same Prod_ID and Type_ID.

My first try was to make a union query:

```
Select T1.Cust_ID, T1.Prod_ID, T1.Type_ID, T2.Results
From T1 left join T2
On T1.Cust_ID=T1.Cust_ID and T1.Prod_ID=T2.Prod_ID and T1.Type_ID=T2.Type_ID
Where T1.Cust_ID is not Null
Union
Select T1.Cust_ID, T1.Prod_ID, T1.Type_ID, T2.Results
From T1 left join T2
On T1.Prod_ID=T2.Prod_ID and T1.Type_ID=T2.Type_ID
Where T1.Cust_ID is Null
```

I know its a brute approach, but it works for one field. Now I need to have this same type of condition on more than one field and I was wondering how  to do it dynamically. I looked for a solution on-line but couldn't find anyone in this exact situation.

Any ideas or links to the same question?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I hope i understood you correctly. This could to the trick for you:

```
   SELECT
          SWITCH(
            T1.Cust_ID IS NULL,T2.Cust_ID,
            T1.Cust_ID IS NOT NULL, T1.Cust_ID
          ) AS Cust_ID,
          SWITCH(
            T1.Cust_ID IS NULL,T2.Prod_ID,
            T1.Cust_ID IS NOT NULL, T1.Prod_ID
          ) AS Prod_ID,
          SWITCH(
            T1.Cust_ID IS NULL,T2.Type_ID,
            T1.Cust_ID IS NOT NULL, T1.Type_ID
          ) AS Cust_ID,
          T2.Results
        FROM T1
        FULL OUTER JOIN T2
        ON T1.Prod_ID  = T2.Prod_ID
        AND T1.Type_ID = T2.Type_ID
```

Comment: Turns out there is no "CASE" function in ACCESS :-(

Comment: Sorry, I Didn't notice you using MSACCESS. I edited code snippet. Try to use it now.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. Turns out MS ACCESS don't support full outer joins either.